# Find Highest and 2nd Highest value of row and Save Column names in new Column

Tags: r

I have a question. Need to find first 2 maximum values from a table and print their name in new column. Below is data set

```
ID  Fail1   Fail2   Fail3   Fail4
43324   10  5   4   9
42059   12  7   6   11
43321   14  9   8   13
43414   16  11  10  15
41517   18  13  12  17
43711   20  15  14  19
55675   22  17  16  21
55769   24  19  18  23
55631   26  21  20  25
```

Now for every ID, need first and second max causes of Fail concatenated in a new column added in same table.
[Data set Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di7YR.png)

Comment: You should show what you have tried. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach which reshapes from wide to long format, picks the two max values for each ID and appends the respective column names as a new column to the original data.frame (using `join`):

```
library(data.table)
DF[melt(DF, id.var = "ID")[order(-value), .(top = toString(variable[1:2])), by = ID], 
   on = "ID"]
```

> ```
>       ID Fail1 Fail2 Fail3 Fail4          top
> 1: 55631    26    21    20    25 Fail1, Fail4
> 2: 55769    24    19    18    23 Fail1, Fail4
> 3: 55675    22    17    16    21 Fail1, Fail4
> 4: 43711    20    15    14    19 Fail1, Fail4
> 5: 41517    18    13    12    17 Fail1, Fail4
> 6: 43414    16    11    10    15 Fail1, Fail4
> 7: 43321    14     9     8    13 Fail1, Fail4
> 8: 42059    12     7     6    11 Fail1, Fail4
> 9: 43324    10     5     4     9 Fail1, Fail4
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "ID  Fail1   Fail2   Fail3   Fail4
43324   10  5   4   9
42059   12  7   6   11
43321   14  9   8   13
43414   16  11  10  15
41517   18  13  12  17
43711   20  15  14  19
55675   22  17  16  21
55769   24  19  18  23
55631   26  21  20  25"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
dat$top2 = apply(dat[ , grepl("Fail", names(dat))], 1, function(r) {
  paste(names(r)[which(rank(-r, ties.method="first") %in% c(1:2))], collapse=", ")
  })
```

If there's a tie for first, this will give all the columns that tie for first (even if there are more than two) and none of the columns that tie for second. If there's a tie for second and no tie for first, then this will give the column with the highest value and all columns that tie for second.

Here's a `tidyverse` version of @Uwe's answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat = dat %>% left_join(
  dat %>% 
    gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
    arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice(1:2) %>% 
    summarise(top2 = paste(key, collapse=", "))
)
```

Comment: Will this also work if any column of the data.frame is of type `character`, e.g., `ID`?

Comment: Thanks, however this will print the ID Name also. To remove ID name and just print max 2 we can use modified code.

Comment: dat$result = apply(dat[-1], 1, function(r) {
  paste(names(r)[which(rank(-r, ties.method="min") %in% c(1:2))], collapse=", ")
})

Comment: I've updated the code to try and address the comments.